# Stripe webhook POST route does not have req.user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, stripe-payments

I am testing Stripe webhooks locally using ngrok, so that the webhooks can be sent to an endpoint on localhost.

I want to test saving customer and payment information to my database, however, it seems like the middleware isn't attaching req.user (set by Passport) like it is on any other route. This makes it a lot less convenient in terms of accessing the authenticated user.

I could do the database work on the routes where I receive a Stripe token, but the bulk of useful information is sent as a webhook. Another option is to save the charge id or customer id at that stage, and then to look up the user at a later stage, but again this seems like unnecessary work.

I'm a little confused as to why this is, unless I'm missing something super obvious.

```
router.post('/stripe/webhook', (req, res) => {

   console.log(req.user); //undefined
   res.sendStatus(200);

});
```

Comment: What was your solution to this? I am having an issue, I need my req.user credentials in the get request. using passport which stores the req.user

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detail of Stripe webhook mechanism [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

**You need to parse the `body` of the `request` which is holding the payload JSON**

**Example receiving endpoint :**

```
app.post("/my/webhook/url", function(request, response) {

  // Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
  var event_json = JSON.parse(request.body);
  // Do something with event_json
  response.send(200);
});
```

You can test the your receiving endpoint by test JSON which you can found in `Event API` of Stripe! And you send test JSON using many app like POSTMAN
(having also a chrome app)

Comment: That's not the issue here Zico, I am already parsing the JSON response with body-parser.

Comment: I'm a little unclear, the request is originating asynchronously, directly from Stripe, it wouldn't contain any sort of detail of the authenticated user --- only details of the Stripe object (customer id, charge id, any metadata you've set, etc). What value are you expecting `req.user` to be populated with?